# change height of multiple divs in proportion of window height

Tags: php, jquery, css, height, each

I'm using a slideshow on my website with jquery cycle.
all my slides contain a div named "cartouche_bottom_inside", and I need to adapt each of this divs to the height of my window.
my slides are generated via php, so basicaly if have this kind of structure :

```
<div id="slideshow">

    <div class="slide">

        <div class="cartouche_bottom_inside">

        /* my content */

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="slide">

        <div class="cartouche_bottom_inside">

        /* my content */

        </div>

    </div>


        <div class="cartouche_bottom_inside">

        /* my content */

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="slide">

        <div class="cartouche_bottom_inside">

        /* my content */

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

with this jquery code I can change the "cartouche_bottom_inside" divs height, depending of various custom variables.

```
function margin_bottom_cartouche(){

    var cartouche_bottom_inside_H = $(".cartouche_bottom_content").height();
    var margin_bottom_cartouche_add = windowH - cartouche_bottom_inside_H - cartouche_top_visible_H;

        if (cartouche_bottom_inside_H < windowH) {

            $(".cartouche_bottom_content").css("height",cartouche_bottom_inside_H + margin_bottom_cartouche_add -cartouche_top_visible_H);
        }       
}
```

It works, but 1st, in my if statement, $(".cartouche_bottom_content").height() gets me the sum of all my "cartouche_bottom_inside" divs.

and then it applies the $(".cartouche_bottom_content").height to all my divs (depending of the tallest ".cartouche_bottom_content" div.

What I'm trying to do is :

1st : to check each divs height first

2nd : then check for each divs if the height is smaller to my window height.

3rd : then apply the height to each div independently.

Which means I'll have different heights for all my ".cartouche_bottom_content" divs.

in fact I'm trying to find a way to have a foreach statement, like in php for example...

can anybody help me with this ?

thanks a lot for your time,

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're trying to have it so that each div is set to the view height of the window. In that case and if you're comfortable [supporting only modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), you can look into the CSS unit [VH and VW](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) for View Height and View Width respectively to set the width and height of your divs.

As for your current JS, I'm not too sure what you're trying to accomplish with your code, if you are trying to set each div to the window height, you wouldn't need to do all those complicated measurements and just set height to client height?

Comment: in fact I already have my method to set the height of my divs. what I'm trying to do is to calculate independently all my div (as they share the same class), and then set the height independently to my divs... do you understand what I mean ?

Comment: Oh I see what you're trying to do now. Yes there is a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function in jQuery that allows you to access each div individually that matches a selector.